# Updating value of table to value of view using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list of restaurants, with an associated list of reviews.  I made a view that holds the id of the restaurants, and the average of the review ratings.

Rating (view in db):

```
Id   AvgRating (already calculated in sql based on all review ratings)
1    3.4
2    1.8
```

Restaurant (table in db):

```
Id    AvgRating    Name
1     ...          Wendys
2     ...          McDonalds
```

I have a list of both of these entities.  What would be the best way to update Restaurant.AvgRating to equal the view's AvgRating? Is it best to do it directly in sql or using EF?

Comment: is this one time migration? And after migration, you are going to remove the Restaurant Rating column from table?

Comment: I think that the best way is just write a simple sql update using join.

Comment: @user1672994 No, I need to recompute the average each time a new review comes in.  I know this is doable using triggers, but unsure how to do it in EF

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the db.Entry() method of your DBContext.
For example:

```
public void updateAvg(List<Restaurante> restaurantes)
    {
        using (WebMVCContext db = new WebMVCContext())
        {
            foreach (var item in restaurantes)
            {
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I used this following class:

```
public class Restaurante
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Avg { get; set; }
}
```

The Entry method to update or insert in the context and the SaveChanges to commit this items to your database.